# Spring packages component scan trouble

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am making a Spring Maven Project using Hibernate and Spring Security(basic logging form with little tic-tac-toe game) . Everything worked fine since I decided not to use single Root WebApplicationContext and divide it into Root and Servlet Context(I was told that using single one is incorrect, because you can @Autowire controller into repository or service which is forbidden).

Here is my project structure:

[image]

ServletConfig class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller"})
public class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

}
```

RootConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"services","dao"})
public class RootConfig {
}
```

WebAppInitializer:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{RootConfig.class};
}

protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {return new Class[]{ServletConfig.class};}

protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
}
```

Because one of my classes has to be made with new() and also requires Autowiring one of services I am using ApplicationContextHolder:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext context;

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    context = applicationContext;
}

public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
    return context;
}
}
```

Which is used to inject in this way:

```
this.userService = (UserService) ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean("userService");
```

When I try to run it by Tomcat I am getting an ERROR:

> 2016-11-20 17:09:54 WARN  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:549 -             Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   2016-11-20 17:09:54 ERROR ContextLoader:351 - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Here are my questions:

1. Is the @ComponentScan made properly? Maybe it is missing some packages to scan(like configuration?)?
2. Is it possible to use only one Config class? Just like:
   @ComponentScan("everything")?
3. Do I have to scan packages with Spring Security Configuration in Root or Servlet Config Classes?

@EDIT 1:

Here is my ApplicationContextHolder class

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext context;

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    context = applicationContext;
}

public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
    return context;
}
}
```

@EDIT 2:

HibernateConfiguration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com/configuration")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.entities");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}

}
```

Here I am using AppContextHolder:

```
@Data
public class Game {

@Autowired
private UserService userService; ....



public Game() {

this.userService = (UserService) ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean("userService");
}
```

Comment: I would recommend that you put all your packages below a common package like "com.app" and create a class Application in com.app that is annotated with @SpringBootApplication. That annotation includes a componentScan that scans all subpackages.

Comment: Thanks . Is there going to be any problems to create @Autowired fields in test directory with a configuration like that?

Comment: how do you use ApplicationContextHolder, can you show that class

Comment: Having @Autowired in test directory you have to make sure of course that only test classes have dependencies to that bean, Otherwise Spring would not start since it does not scan the test directory - even if it has the same package.

You are saying "Because one of my classes has to be made with new() and also requires Autowiring one of services I am using ApplicationContextHolder:". Do you mean you have services without an empty constructor?

Comment: Your configuration is correct for the component scan but it is missing hibernate configuration, that is the reason why it fails. As you can see in the error you are missing `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` bean that you have `@Autowire`d in the `roleDaoImpl`.

Comment: I added my ApplicationContextHolder and HIbernateConfiguration classes to the question.

Comment: Have you imported your hibernate configuration in the `RootConfig`? Something like `@Import(HibernateConfiguration.class)` at class level.